# How to return HTTP error status code in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the most efficient way to return an error number or error status code in JavaScript / NodeJS?  For example, I would like to return a status code (or error code) of 401 in the following snippet:

```
var login = function (params, callback) {

    var email       = params.email || '',
        password    = params.password || '';

    if (!isValidEmail(email)) { 
        return callback(new Error('Email address required', 401)); 
    }

    // Do something else
};
```

The login method, above, would be called as follows:

```
authRouter.post('/login', function(req, res) {
   svc.login(req.body, function (err, response) {
       if (err) {
           err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 401;
           return res.status(err.statusCode).send({ message: err.message });
       } else {
           return res.send(response);
       }
   });
});
```

The goal here is to have the `err.statusCode` (or similar) set in the method and passed back via the callback.  Basically, I'm looking for a shorthand version of this:

```
var err = new Error('Email address required');
err.statusCode = 401;
return callback(err);
```

Comment: You mean, send to the client? What framework are you using?

Comment: Using Node ... shouldn't matter what I do with it, I just want the error object to contain the numeric value.

Comment: If that's the problem, just use a helper `function StatusError(stat, msg) { var err = new Error(msg); err.statusCode = stat; return err; }` then

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own error class for something like this. I've done something similar on several projects:

```
class HttpError extends Error {
    constructor (message, statusCode) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it the way you expected it to work:

```
return callback(new HttpError('Email address required', 401));
```

Personally I prefer to create individual error types for the kinds of error my app use to make the code more readable. When you're in a rush, especially if you have junior developers working on your code, you will find that most people won't remember what `401` error is. I normally do something like this:

```
class UnauthorizedError extends Error {
    constructor (message) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = 401;
    }
}

class ForbiddenError extends Error {
    constructor (message) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = 403;
    }
}

class NotFoundError extends Error {
    constructor (message) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = 404;
    }
}
```

So I'd use them like this:

```
return callback(new UnauthorizedError('Email address required'));
```

IMHO this makes the code more readable and also makes the error codes self-documenting in the source code.

Answer (score -1):

In nodeJS you should ever return your error in the first argument of your callbacks.

```
myFunctionThatDoesSomethingAsync (callback) {
  doSomethingAsync('asanas', function (){
    //do something 
    return callback(err,results)
  })
}

myFunctionThatDoesSomethingAsync(function (err,results) {
  if (!err)
    doSomethingWith(results)
})
```

read more: http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/

Sorry I read your question again and ysing NodeJS HTTP response you should do something like:

```
res.writeHead(401, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Email address required'');
```

Comment: That's not the question.  My goal is to include a numeric value (a status code) on the error object.